# Is there any source talking about some stock behave similar to Gamestop from 12/2020 to 2/2021?

Tags: stock-market, trading

From 12/2020 to 2/2021 is the time that the price of Gamestop stocks drastically increases. I am wondering is there any US stock that also behaves the same (incidental increase) during this time period? Or in another word, is there any source to know some stocks behave the same during this time period? I found some [here](https://www.fool.com/investing/2021/03/07/forget-gamestop-amc-sundial-best-stocks-to-buy-now/).

P/S: Please let me know if my post is in the wrong stack exchange. I think Economics SE is a good place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these sources are citing events that happened pretty recently, but I hope it helps!

https://www.nytimes.com/2021/08/04/business/robinhood-stock-price.html

https://www.cnbc.com/2021/08/24/gamestop-surges-30percent-to-lead-meme-stock-rally-in-otherwise-boring-market.html

https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2021-06-09/the-meme-stocks-keep-coming

https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/top-meme-stocks-to-buy-right-now-5-in-focus-2021-07-07

https://www.nytimes.com/2021/08/04/business/robinhood-stock-price.html

--

Another popular one around the time of the Gamestop rally was AMC.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: The above review option was a poor choice by me. What I meant to convey was that this is a link only answer; please copy the gist of the information into the body of your answer. To illustrate this problem: the OP actually mentions AMC in their link, but you did not catch that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subreddit entirely made for that: r/Shortsqueeze

https://www.reddit.com/r/Shortsqueeze/